# mysql query not returning results

Tags: mysql

I am executing this query

```
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(startTime,'%m/%d/%Y') = '7/15/2012'
```

and `startTime` column has this value **'2012-07-15 12:00:00'**

But this is not returning any results. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change here:

```
7/15/2012
```

to:

```
07/15/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation for the `DATE_FORMAT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), `%m` is "Month, numeric (`00`..`12`)". Note the zero-padding. So you need to write `'07/15/2012'` rather than `'7/15/2012'`.

(And in case you're wondering — I have no idea what month #0 is. So far as I'm aware, the months range from `01` to `12`. Maybe some locales do have a month #0?)